# JavaScript: One Canvas Multiple Textures

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to render multiple images on a single canvas, but seem to be overlooking something:

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = 4086;
canvas.height = 4086;

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var loadedImages = 0;

for (var j=0; j<4; j++) {
  var url = 'https://via.placeholder.com/2048x2048';
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function(j) {
    var w = 2048;
    var h = 2048;
    var x = (j % 2) * w;
    var y = (Math.floor(j / 2)) * h;
    console.log(img, x, y, w, h)
    ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, w, h, x, y, w, h);
    if (++loadedImages == 4) {
      document.body.appendChild(canvas)
    }
  }.bind(null, j)
  img.src = url;
}
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 500px;
}
```

Does anyone see what I'm missing? Any help others can offer would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Only one of my images is added to the canvas - not all four.

Comment: Don't you need to multiply `x` and `y` by 2048?

Comment: @Pointy Whoops, yes, but that doesn't display the other images in recent Chrome...

Comment: I think you want the simpler `drawImage(img, x, y, w, h)` API.

Comment: @Pointy, thanks that does it, but why doesn't the longer drawImage call work above?

Comment: @Pointy if you make your response an answer I'll accept it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the long-form API to draw the image, which is designed to select a *portion* of your source image to draw onto the canvas. You really only need the "short" version, because (I think) you want to draw the entire image four times.

When you use the long form, the code is requesting pixels that don't exist in the source image because it's only 2048x2048 pixels in size.